# VBA can't find text box- possibly an issue with JavaScript hiding box

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel

I'm trying to set up a VBA module which will automatically log in to a website, navigate to a specific page, and input data from Excel to check if the data is permissible. I've gotten to the final page, where I will be plugging in the data from Excel, but am having trouble actually changing the values of the text boxes on the webpage. I suspect that this is an issue caused by the JavaScript of the cell.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="getNMContext().handleTextBoxOnKeyPress(event);" onblur="handleTextBoxOnBlur(this, '',event);" onfocus="handleTextBoxOnFocus(this, '');" onchange="getNMContext().handleTextBoxOnChange(event);" style="width: 200px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" name="DISPLAY_SearchParameters_MemberID" id="DISPLAY_SearchParameters_MemberID_ID" maxlength="8" title="">
```

The above is an example of one field which I need to modify. Using

```
IE.document.getElementById("DISPLAY_SearchParameters_MemberID_ID").value = "text"
```

doesn't update the field, instead returning error 424, informing me that an object is required (so no box with the ID is even being detected).

What reason could there be that VBA is unable to detect the text field, even when given the ID?

I would post a picture of the box, but I don't have the reputation required (I'm a new user).

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, after toying around a bit, definitely an iFrame. I still don't really know how to deal with that, though. I'll try reading through other posts.

Answer (score 0):

If this text box is stored in iFrame first you need to get the reference to this iFrame and then use its `ContentWindow` property:

```
Dim frame As Object
Dim textBox As Object

Set frame = IE.Document.getElementById("frame_id")
Set textBox = frame.contentWindow.Document.getElementById("DISPLAY_SearchParameters_MemberID_ID")
textBox.value = "text"
```